# Android app doesnt send picture to database PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-hosting

I have a problem, because the picture isnt sent to my database. I used different PHP file which doesnt decode picture again and everything works fine, all results appear in my database, but when I try to connect to that file it doesnt work. This is the php that doesnt work properly:

```
<?php

header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){

$username = $_POST["username"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];

$decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

$path = 'place on server where I want pictures to be sent' ;

$file = fopen($path, 'wb');

$is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
fclose($file);

if($is_written > 0){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xx", "xx", "xx");
    $query = "INSERT INTO meals(username, description, image) values('$username', '$description' , '$path');";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if($result){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}   
}

?>
```

And that one send details properly but not in the way I would like to:

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xx", "xx", "xx");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO images (username, description, image) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $description, $encoded_string);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);


?>
```

Is it casued beacause I have to change FTP settings?

the second code passes all data to database but image is in base64 format so there are plenty characters and it runs slowly. What I want to do is to be able to use the first code, but it doesn't decodes base64 to actual image I am sending and it shows no result in database nor folder in server.

Comment: Pretty unclear what works and what not works. Very unclear what you want.

Comment: @greenapps Well, the second code passes all data to database but image is in base64 format so there are plenty characters and it runs slowly. What I want to do is to be able to use the first code, but it doesn't decodes base64 to actual image I am sending and it shows no result in database nor folder in server.

Comment: @greenapps I want the first code work properly.

Comment: Well then what does not work properly. Obviously it decodes already. What does it save to file then? Did you check `$is_written` ? Which `$path` did you really use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
$path="uploads"."/".rand()."_".time().".jpeg";  //uploads is folder, file name is composed of random number+underscore+time.jpeg
$upload_url="http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/".$path;
if(file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($encoded_string))){
    //file uploaded, insert $upload_url into database(Type varchar)
}else{
    //echo "file could not uploaded";
}
```

Comment: You're great man, thanks a lot! But where was the problem in my previous code?

Comment: @D.B. My pleasure! May be your $path declaration had problem(I am not sure). I don't see any error otherwise.

Comment: Maybe the path caused the problem, I'm not sure as well, anyway thanks!